# flow for test validation

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

What would be the best way to test a validation request? For example. If a class has 4 attributes, all required, and one of them with a minimum of letters, and another being of type email.

It would be wise to test all possibilities, such as a test for filled fields or not, or if the attribute has the number of letters or just make sure that an error message is displayed, without worrying about the attribute itself.

In the API I'm taking care of, I did a test for every possible situation, but some tests will get really big

Comment: This can be achieved when testing the routes to your api. You could use a data provider to create different iterations of tests with different data (wrong format etc).

Comment: I rather say you are following a convention. If you see your tests are increasing every day it's totally fine because you are writing tests for every scenario. you should not worry about it.